# Is this the Chofetz Chaim?

Tags: history, rabbis, provenance, pictures, chofetz-chaim

What is the story behind this picture being known as the image of the great Rabbi Yisrael Meir Kagan(Chafetz Chaim)? Is it him in fact? Where does it come from?

[image: CC]

The only true picture (that I am aware of) shows him sitting down, at a distance and is rather unclear:

[image: CC_real]

[This website](http://www.mywesternwall.net/2011/09/07/pictures-of-the-chofetz-chaim-which-one-is-real.html) mentions that the first image could be that of his Shamas or wagon driver. It describes the above photo (the second picture) as follows:
"The above picture was taken in Radin and the Chofetz Chaim is seen speaking to his oldest son, Rabbi Leib Poupko who eventually became Rav in Radin and President of the Mizrachi in Poland. He passed away in 1939. The CC’s last Rebbetzin, also who was an adopted daughter, is standing behind him. There’s also a young woman in the picture standing next to the Chofetz Chaim. Rav Chaim Wolkin, the Mashgiach in Ateres, is seen posing (in a walking pose, which was apparently a popular thing in those days) in the street between the photographer and the house".

Are there any other *photos* of the Chofetz Chaim to which we can compare the first picture for authentication?

Comment: The Living Torah Museum has another photo which they claim is the clearest one ever discovered: http://www.torahmuseum.com/Viewer_personalities/Person01_ChofetzChaim.html

Comment: Also see this discussion: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/one-one-photograph-of-the-chofetz-chaim

Comment: New evidence: http://somehowfrum.blogspot.com/2015/02/cinematic-chofetz-chaim-corroborated.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, the painting is based on a popular picture of the Chofetz Chaim, which can be seen in The Schwadron Collection of the National Library of Israel (Jerusalem). The archive lists the picture as following:

> A photo portrait of Rabbi Israel Meir Cohen ("Chafetz Chaim"): printed
> silver, black and white, 7X12 cm. Portfolio also includes a copy of
> this portrait, which contains on the back a summarized biography of
> the subject, written by Dr. Abraham Schwadron in Yiddish.

It is undated but clearly identified by the archive as the Chofetz Chaim. Here is that picture:

[image: black and white photograph of Chofetz Chaim]

Although it is undated, we know it was circulated in his lifetime. The collection also includes clippings from Polish newspapers and other sources that reprint the picture, and label his name with *shlita* (may he live for many good days amen). For example:

[image: newspaper print of the above black and white portrait of Chofetz Chaim]

The collection also contains another picture of the Chofetz Chaim from a newspaper, which alleges that he is 90 in the picture (notice the cane, also seen in the sitting picture you included):

[image: newspaper print of a different photograph of Chofetz Chaim]

Comment: who was "Dr. Abraham Schwadron"?

Comment: He was a prominent Zionist writer of the early 20th century, known as Avraham Sharon in Israel, who established an amazing collection at the National Library. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Sharon

Comment: This picture mentioned http://i.stack.imgur.com/vs7MF.jpg doesn't add up; from the video and the picture of the Chofetz Chaim in front of his house, he doesn't look at all like he does in this picture which is allegedly a photo of him. Maybe it's a picture of another butcher... IDK, B'Emet.

Answer (score 15):

Click *[here](http://youtu.be/87XlDRjmPME?t=56s)* to see this video that has been making the rounds on Jewish sites recently has a short scene of the Chafetz Chaim.

Here are some screen caps:

[image: Chofetz Chaim video]
[image: Chofetz Chaim video]
[image: Chofetz Chaim video]
[image: Chofetz Chaim video]

Comment: The Chofetz Chaim appears at 0:56, http://youtu.be/87XlDRjmPME?t=56s

Comment: @Danny Nice work my technologically advanced friend. Thank you.