# Paintings and Sculptures of Rabbis Throughout the Ages

Tags: history, historical-figures, pictures

There are many paintings or sculptures of Rabbis from throughout history, like the Vilna Gaon (paintings), Maharal (statue), and Rambam (statue).

Are they accurate (or at least somewhat accurate) depictions of this people?

(The same may be asked about non-Jewish philosophers and other figures who have been made into statues).

Comment: Chofetz Chaim: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30731/5323

Comment: The classic picture of the Rambam doesn't have *peyot*. We're pretty sure it's not him.

Comment: This is probably too broad; do you have a particular rabbi you'd like to ask about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Painting of the Rambam; not earlier than 15th century (i.e. unreliable) see [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3678793/).

Statue of Mahral; by sculptor [Ladislav Šaloun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladislav_%C5%A0aloun) according to [here](http://www.israelimages.com/see_image_details.php?idi=23905) (i.e. unreliable).

Painting of the Gra possibly authentic as it is relatively contemporary see [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vilna_Gaon_authentic_portrait.JPG). See however [here](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2009/10/salomon-maimon-and-portraits-of-vilna.html) that the popular picture is inauthentic, but that there is an authentic picture of him:[image: authentic Gra]

For a general discussion of the historical accuracy of art see [here](http://decodedpast.com/studying-history-through-art-is-it-accurate/1343).